# Redefining a define

Tags: c, casting, preprocessor

I'm reviewing some code and I stumbled across this:

In a header file we have this MAGIC_ADDRESS defined

```
#define ANOTHER_ADDRESS ((uint8_t*)0x40024000)
#define MAGIC_ADDRESS (ANOTHER_ADDRESS + 4u)
```

And then peppered throughout the code in various files we have things like this:

`*(uint32_t*)MAGIC_ADDRESS = 0;`
and
`*(uint32_t*)MAGIC_ADDRESS = SOME_OTHER_DEFINE;`

This compiles, apparently works, and it throws no linter errors. `MAGIC_ADDRESS = 0;` without the cast does not compile as I would expect.

So my questions are:

- Why in the world would we ever want to do this rather than just making a uint32_t in the first place?
- How does this actually work? I thought preprocessor defines were untouchable, how are we managing to cast one?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's not redefining it, it's dereferencing it and assigning to the memory at the specified address.

Comment: The cast, is because you can't use a number as a pointer without it. Although the use case is recasting to a different pointer type. `MAGIC_ADDRESS = 0;` does not compile because you removed the `*` as well as the second cast.

Comment: The magic address probably corresponds to a memory-mapped hardware device.

Comment: Remember, the macro is replaced during preprocessing. So the code that's executed is `*(uint32_t*)((uint8_t*)0x40024000) = SOME_OTHER_DEFINE;`

Comment: "preprocessor defines were untouchable" ??

Comment: Remember: before your code gets seen by the compiler, all macro substitutions are done in the preprocessor. So there's no such thing as "casting" a preprocessor macro. By the time the compiler (which actually understands casting, as opposed to the preprocessor) sees the code, the macro has been substituted.

Answer (score 3):

> Why in the world would we ever want to do this rather than just making a uint32_t in the first place?

That's a fair question.  One possibility is that `ANOTHER_ADDRESS` is used as a base address for more than one kind of data, but the code fragments presented do not show any reason why `ANOTHER_ADDRESS` should not be defined to expand to an expression of type `uint32_t *`.  Note, however, that if that change were made then the definition of `MAGIC_ADDRESS` would need to be changed to `(ANOTHER_ADDRESS + 1u)`.

> How does this actually work? I thought preprocessor defines were untouchable, how are we managing to cast one?

Where an in-scope macro identifier appears in C source code, the macro's replacement text is substituted.  Simplifying a bit, if the replacement text contains macro identifiers, too, then those are then replaced with *their* replacement text, *etc*..  Nowhere in your code fragments as a macro being cast, *per se*, but the fully-expanded result expresses some casts.

For example, this ...

```
*(uint32_t*)MAGIC_ADDRESS = 0;
```

... expands to ...

```
*(uint32_t*)(ANOTHER_ADDRESS + 4u) = 0;
```

... and then on to ...

```
*(uint32_t*)(((uint8_t*)0x40024000) + 4u) = 0;
```

.  There are no casts of macros there, but there are (valid) casts of macros' replacement text.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the cast that allows the assignment to work, it's the `*` dereferencing operator. The macro expands to a pointer constant, and you can't reassign a constant. But since it's a pointer you can assign to the memory it points to. So if you wrote

```
*MAGIC_ADDRESS = 0;
```

you wouldn't get an error.

The cast is necessary to assign to a 4-byte field at that address, rather than just a single byte, since the macro expands to a `uint8_t*`. Casting it to `uint32_t*` make it a 4-byte assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define ANOTHER_ADDRESS ((uint8_t*)0x40024000)
#define MAGIC_ADDRESS (ANOTHER_ADDRESS + 4u)
```

> And then peppered throughout the code in various files we have things like this:

```
*(uint32_t*)MAGIC_ADDRESS = 0;
```

That's the problem - you don't want anything repetitive peppered throughout. Instead, this is what more-or-less idiomatic embedded C code would look like:

```
// Portable to compilers without void* arithmetic extension
#define BASE_ADDRESS ((uint8_t*)0x40024000)
#define REGISTER1 (*(uint32_t*)(ANOTHER_ADDRESS + 4u))
```

You can then write `REGISTER1 = 42` or `if (REGISTER1 != 42)` etc. As you may imagine, this is normally used to for memory-mapped peripheral control registers.

If you're using gcc or clang, there's another layer of type safety available as an extension: you don't really want the compiler to allow `*BASE_ADDRESS` to compile, since presumably you only want to access registers - the `*BASE_ADDRESS` expression shouldn't pass a code review. And thus:

```
// gcc, clang, icc, and many others but not MSVC
#define BASE_ADDRESS ((void*)0x40024000)
#define REGISTER1 (*(uint32_t*)(ANOTHER_ADDRESS + 4u))
```

Arithmetic on `void*` is a gcc extension adopted most compilers that don't come from Microsoft, and it's handy: the `*BASE_ADDRESS` expression won't compile, and that's a good thing.

I imagine that the `BASE_ADDRESS` is the address of the battery-backed RAM on an STM32 MCU, in which case the "REGISTER" interpretation is incorrect, since all you want is to persist some application data, and you're using C, not assembly language, and there's this handy thing we call structures - absolutely use a structure instead of this ugly hack. The things beings stored in that non-volatile area aren't registers, they are just fields in a structure, and the structure itself is stored in a non-volatile fashion:

```
#define BKPSRAM_BASE_ ((void*)0x40024000)
#define nvstate (*(NVState*)BKPSRAM_BASE_)

enum NVLayout { NVVER_1 = 1, NVVER_2 = 2 };

struct {
  // Note: This structure is persisted in NVRAM.
  // Do not reorder the fields.
  enum NVLayout layout;
  // NVVER_1 fields
  uint32_t value1;
  uint32_t value2;
  ...
  /* sometime later after a release */
  // NVVER_2 fields
  uint32_t valueA;
  uint32_t valueB;
} typedef NVState;
```

Use:

```
if (nvstate.layout >= NVVER1) {
  nvstate.value1 = ...;
  if (nvstate.value2 != 42) ...
}
```

And here we come to the crux of the problem: your code review was focused on the minutiae, but you should have also divulged the big picture. If my big picture guess is correct - that it's all about sticking some data in a battery-backed RAM, then an actual data structure should be used, not macro hackery and manual offset management. Yuck.

And yes, you'll need that `layout` field for forward compatibility unless the entire NVRAM area is pre-initialized to zeroes, and you're OK with zeroes as default values.

This approach easily allows you to copy the NVRAM state, e.g. if you wanted to send it over the wire for diagnostic purposes - you don't have to worry about how much data is there, just use `sizeof(NVState)` for passing it to functions such as `fwrite`, and you can even use a working copy of that NV data - all without a single memcpy:

```
NVState wkstate = nvstate;
/* user manipulates the state here */
if (OK_pressed)
  nvstate = wkstate;
else if (Cancel_pressed)
  wkstate = nvstate;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to assign values to a specific place in memory using MACROs
   allows you to do so in a way that is relatively easy to read (and if you need to
   use another address later - just change the macro definition)
2. The macro is translated by the preprocessor to a value. When you then de-reference
   it you get access to the memory which you can read or write to. This has nothing to
   do with the string that is used as a label by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Both definitions are wrong I afraid (or at least not completely correct)

It should be defined as a pointer to `volatile` value if pointers are referencing hardware registers.

```
#define ANOTHER_POINTER ((volatile uint8_t*)0x40024000)
#define MAGIC_APOINTER (ANOTHER_ADDRESS + 4u)
```

I was defined as `uint8_t *` pointer because probably author wanted pointer arithmetic to be done on the ***byte*** level.